# How to create a custom 404 page for my Django/Apache?

Tags: python, django, apache

I know that you use `.htaccess` in the document-root directory in standard Apache.
What if I use Django?  Can someone give me step by step how to create a custom 404 page?

Comment: In general the Django documentation is really great. Have a look at the [Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/) for a great intoduction to Django. They cover the 404 page in [chapter 3](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default 404 handler calls 404.html .  You could edit that if you don't need anything fancy or can override the 404 handler by setting the handler404 view -- [more here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-404-page-not-found-view)